# How to add footer to newspaper template

Tags: header-footer, newspaper

I am using the newspaper template to typeset a newspaper. My results are here [image: my journal]

### Qestion:

However, I would like to have a footer as shown in the authors example: **see highlighted with yellow** [image: authors example] .

There I would like to add contact info or some link to a possible future website.

I do not know how to do this. I have tried fancyheader but that seems to distort the subsequent pages look. Anyway, I was not able to get good results with it ... I am not a latex expert.

How can I have something similar to what is shown in the authors example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I do not know how to make what I see in the authors example! Please see what is highlighted with yellow on the authors example snip. What else can I say ?

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a "footnote".

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner thank you for the clarification. I guess so ! With this new direction I found \footnote{text for footnote} ... Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved in comments by clarifying that the "feature" is called `footnote` (and *not* `footer`): `\footnote{text for footnote}`.